# INotifyPropertyChanged Binding to DataTemplate in GridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, inotifypropertychanged

I have successfully bound a column in a DataGrid to an observable collection with objects implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

This is the xaml:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Name="Name" FieldName="Stapel" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
```

And the property in the objects class:

```
public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
```

But in another column I am using a Template:

```
<dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
                <Rectangle Height="19" Width="19" Fill="{Binding Path=Data.StatusColor}"></Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The Fill property of the rectangle is bound to a "calculated" property:

```
public SolidColorBrush StatusColor
{
    get
    {
        if (StapelStatus == StapelStatus.Neu)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CornflowerBlue);
        }
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkOrange);
    }
}
```

Some other property setters, which change the value of `StapelStatus` are calling

```
OnPropertyChanged("StatusColor");
```

I thought this would be enough to change also the color in the rectangle color in the grid column. But unfortunately when the `StapelStatus` is changed and `OnPropertyChanged("StatusColor")` is called the grid doesn't reflect this change. I guess that I have to change somehow the binding in the `DataTemplate`. Can someone please give me an advice?

Comment: Why do you have `Data.` in the Path of the StatusColor binding?

Comment: To be frank, I have no clue why. I have found this in a working example. If I remove the Data. the value wont appear at all in the DataTemplate.

Comment: Are you sure the DataContext for the DataTemplate is correct? Is Name and StatusColor properties of the same class?

Comment: Another tip: You can use the static [System.Windows.Media.Brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.aspx) class instead of creating new brushes (`Brushes.CornflowerBlue` and `Brushes.DarkOrange`)

Comment: Do I have to set the DataContext for the DataTemplate manually? The Template is inside GridColumn, inside GridControl and I set the DataContext for the GridControl to the observable list. And thanks for the Brush tip.

Comment: can you put a TextBlock in place of rectangle with binding path "." to find out what is exactly therein context of data template.

Comment: Hi @dj, if I use `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" />` inside the CellTemplate the texbox remains empty - what does that mean?

Comment: it means nothing is binded there. there is some binding issue in your code. may be you are not setting the context properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a binding problem in the XAML. Unfortunately I did not set the FieldName property in the GridColumn. I thought the FieldName is only for use in normal GridColumns which don't have any Template.

Below the working XAML for the column:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="" FieldName="StatusColor">
    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Rectangle RadiusX="19" RadiusY="19" Height="19" Width="19" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Path=Value}"></Rectangle>
                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
public Whatever StapelStatus
{
    get { return _stapelStatus; }
    set
    {
        _stapelStatus = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("StapelStatus");
        StatusColor = value == StapelStatus.Neu ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CornflowerBlue) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkOrange);
    }
}

public Brush StatusColor
{
    get { return _statusColor; }
    set
    {
        _statusColor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("StatusColor");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Snurre, thank you for your suggestion but I get exactly the same behaviour. The setter of StatusColor with "OnPropertyChanged("StatusColor")" will be executed but the grid does not reflect the change.